# How can I pass floaterm to be used by other plugin?

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin

I recently installed Neovim and I'm still configuring it, my usual workflow involves C++ projects based on CMake. Therefore, I installed the [cmake-tools extension](https://github.com/Civitasv/cmake-tools.nvim) and configured. I also installed the [floaterm extension](https://github.com/voldikss/vim-floaterm) as I like this idea of a floating terminal.

So, here's my problem: I want to combine the two, having my CMake extension output and program execution on the floating terminal.

The cmake-tools documentation shows the following:

```lua
require("cmake-tools").setup {
  -- Other settings...
  cmake_terminal = {
    name = "terminal",
    opts = {
      name = "Main Terminal",
      prefix_name = "[CMakeTools]: ", -- This must be included and must be unique, otherwise the terminals will not work. Do not use a simple spacebar " ", or any generic name
      split_direction = "horizontal", -- "horizontal", "vertical"
      split_size = 11,

      -- Window handling
      single_terminal_per_instance = true, -- Single viewport, multiple windows
      single_terminal_per_tab = true, -- Single viewport per tab
      keep_terminal_static_location = true, -- Static location of the viewport if avialable

      -- Running Tasks
      start_insert_in_launch_task = true, -- If you want to enter terminal with :startinsert upon using :CMakeRun
      start_insert_in_other_tasks = true, -- If you want to enter terminal with :startinsert upon launching all other cmake tasks in the terminal. Generally set as false
      focus_on_main_terminal = true, -- Focus on cmake terminal when cmake task is launched. Only used if executor is terminal.
      focus_on_launch_terminal = true, -- Focus on cmake launch terminal when executable target in launched.
    },
  },
}
```

I'm assuming my answer is in this section, however I've tried simply changing
`name="terminal"` to `name="floaterm"` but it didn't work. I've also tried changing it to `name="FloatermNew"` hoping it would call this command, start the floaterm instance and run in it, but it also didn't work. Is there a way to do what I want? I imagine it is possible, since I've been told Neovim is all about customization and making it tailored to my needs.